# Word Interop GetSpellingSuggestions no open document error

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, spelling

Morning Everyone,
Been playing with this for a couple of days and getting no where.  I am creating a custom richtextbox in vb.net that will underline spelling errors and offer suggestions when the misspelled word is right clicked on (I can't believe this isn't default in textboxes/richtextboxes...anyway).  I have the underlining working well but I keep getting the error: This command is not available because no document is open.

**EDIT**

running on desktop, 64 bit, office 2007 is installed.
Here is the entire class and how I am testing the call.  IsWordWrong works great.  SpellingSuggestions fails on wapp.GetSpellingSuggestions(pWord) with the error "This command is not available because no document is open" which according to MSDN and multiple tutorials I have seen, should not happen:

```
Public Class SpellCheckUtility

Private Shared wapp As Word.Application
Private Shared missing As Object = Reflection.Missing.Value

Public Shared Sub StartApp()
    If IsNothing(wapp) Then
        wapp = New Word.Application
        wapp.Visible = False
        wapp.WindowState = 0

    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Function IsWrongWord(ByVal pWord As String) As Boolean
    StartApp()
    Dim oFalse As Object = False
    Dim activedoc As Word.Document = wapp.Documents.Add(, , , oFalse)

    Dim m_range As Word.Range
    m_range = activedoc.Range
    m_range.InsertAfter(pWord)

    Dim SpellErrors As Word.ProofreadingErrors = m_range.SpellingErrors

    Return SpellErrors.Count > 0
End Function

Public Shared Function SpellingSuggestions(ByVal pWord As String) As Generic.List(Of String)
    Dim rtnlist As New Generic.List(Of String)

    If pWord.Length > 0 Then
        StartApp()

        Dim SpellErrors As Word.SpellingSuggestions = wapp.GetSpellingSuggestions(pWord)

        For m_word As Integer = 1 To SpellErrors.Count
            rtnlist.Add(SpellErrors.Item(m_word).Name)
        Next
    End If

    Return rtnlist
End Function
Public Shared Sub dispose()
    If Not (wapp Is Nothing) Then
        Dim m_saveChanges As Object = False
        wapp.Quit(m_saveChanges)
        wapp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

How called:

```
Private Sub btnclick1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnclick1.Click
    Dim wordlist As Generic.List(Of String) = SpellCheckUtility.SpellingSuggestions("thingz")
End Sub
```

I have tried both the wapp.GetSpellingSuggestions and the m_range.GetSpellingSuggestions both with the same results.  I am using  m_range.SpellingErrors somewhere else and that works just fine and the setup to get the range is exactly the same so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!

**adapting this code to what I actually want http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18799/Spell-check-and-underline-the-wrong-word-using-Mic

Comment: Is WPF an option? WPF has a spell check built in to `RichTextBox`es.

Comment: I don't believe so..?  the program is windows forms based and massive (10+ yrs old, millions of lines of code).  Looked at a couple of examples for integrating a wpf control into a windows forms base but looked more complicated than this and would like to keep everything same as base.

Comment: I understand that the code you are trying to emulate works fine; why not starting from this (= a working version) and keep removing/adding features? For example: why writing ` Dim activedoc As Word.Document = wapp.Documents.Add(, , , oFalse)` rather than the original versions? (`m_app.Documents.Add()` or `m_app.Documents.Add_
        (m_template, m_newTemplate, m_documentType, m_visible)`)? `Documents.Add` can include a blank document or load a Word file from a given path; and it seems that your code is not completely defined on this front (no path provided, although some arguments)...

Comment: ... In any case, the problem is clearly in the Word Interop part; thus you should focus your debugging on it. Other alternative might be creating a small application connecting to Word via interop (you can easily find many small codes after a quick research) and doing all the eventual tests on it (i.e., open a document and do all the spell-checking actions). This seems a pretty well-delimited problem which, under the right testing conditions, should be quickly fixed. But better not adding the RichTextBox complexity until having perfectly understood the Word part.

Comment: I did do a straight copy/paste at first.  Got the exact same error in the IsWrongWord() function which started me down the road of alteration to see where things were going wrong.  So far, everything works aside from that single line of code to get the spelling suggestions.

Comment: OK. If the original code is not working fine, better forget about my first comment/advice and focus on the second one :)

Comment: I am just trying to run it from my desktop with office 2007 installed. The exact error is "This command is not available because no document is open".  I have each part that accesses interop isolated and the only line that is throwing the error is the wapp.GetSpellingSuggestions() and according to all MSDN and other misc tutorials, nothing else should be needed.  Hoping someone else might have an idea besides "google it"  :)

Answer (score 0):

whooohoo for 64bit vs 32bit office install quirks!  So my dev machine is 64 but my office install is 32.  Apparently interop just doesn't like that setup and (here on is guessing) it is missing a folder to put the temp open doc when using wapp.Documents.Add() hence the no open doc error.  Instead of creating the folder itself, like it should...and really spelling checks should be a default yes/no flag in the properties of all text input controls by now...seriously, it just fails.

Rant over, here is the line I added to the top of the StartApp() function and everything works fine now.

```
If Not IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\") Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve a similar issue with these symptoms by using

```
Dim activedoc = wapp.Documents.Add()
```

rather than

```
Dim activedoc = wapp.Documents.Add(, , , False)
```